# Pgfplots with gnuplot - list of coordinates, not file

Tags: pgfplots, plot, gnuplot

I want to do a simple graph, where its points will be assigned by a list (NOT a file) of coordinates.

So, I know, that I can do something like this:

```
\addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot, color=blue]{plot "test.dat" };
```

But I need to use it like this:

```
\addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot, color=blue]{plot { (0,0)(1,5)(10,12) } };
```

It looks pretty easy, but I'm somehow not able to find a single mention of using `Pgfplots` with `gnuplot` like this.

So, is it even possible to use it like that? And if it is, then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this **cannot** be done. But to explain why I misuse the answer section.

---

In gnuplot (alone) this could be done by typing e.g.

```
plot '-' w p ls 1, '-' w p ls 2, '-' w p ls 3
1 2
e
2 1
e
3 1.5
e
```

which I simply copied from http://www.gnuplotting.org/plotting-single-points. But when you try to do something similar with PGFPlots `raw gnuplot` feature like

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot gnuplot [raw gnuplot] {
                plot '-'
                    1 2
                    2 1
                    3 1.5
                    e
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

in a file called `minimal.tex`, this will result in a corresponding `minimal.pgf-plot.gnuplot` file

```
set table "minimal.pgf-plot.table"; set format "%.5f"
set format "%.7e";; plot '-' 1 2 2 1 3 1.5 e
```

As you can see, all the line breaks were replaced by spaces and thus results in an empty `minimal-pgf-plot.table` file which then of course results in an "empty" plot (only the axes are drawn).

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Even the negative answer is an answer ;-) Thank you!